# How to implement the Progress Dialog in webview before loading an image?

Tags: android, android-webview

I have a webview in my app that has to load an image,  it loads it fine however it takes a few seconds for it to display.   So what i need to do is to display a progress dialog to inform the user that the page is loading.  (this image is loading from assets folder and not from the web) So this is my code sofar but crashes when i try to run that activity.

```
public MapsFragment(){}
ProgressDialog progress;
WebView myWebView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_maps, container, false);

    WebView webview = (WebView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.webView2);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(false);
    webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index1.html");

    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            progress.show();
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;                
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, final String url) {
            progress.dismiss();
        }
    });

    return rootView;
 }
}
```

And then the error code for this is:

```
11-08 13:19:34.034: E/AndroidRuntime(20600): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-08 13:19:34.034: E/AndroidRuntime(20600): Process: com.test.testguide, PID: 20600
11-08 13:19:34.034: E/AndroidRuntime(20600): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-08 13:19:34.034: E/AndroidRuntime(20600):    at com.test.testguide.MapsFragment$1.onPageFinished(MapsFragment.java:42)
11-08 13:19:34.034: E/AndroidRuntime(20600):    at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewContentsClientAdapter.onPageFinished(WebViewContentsClientAdapter.java:449)
11-08 13:19:34.034: E/AndroidRuntime(20600):    at com.android.org.chromium.android_webview.AwContentsClient$AwWebContentsObserver$1.run(AwContentsClient.java:73)
11-08 13:19:34.034: E/AndroidRuntime(20600):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
11-08 13:19:34.034: E/AndroidRuntime(20600):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
11-08 13:19:34.034: E/AndroidRuntime(20600):    at    android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
11-08 13:19:34.034: E/AndroidRuntime(20600):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5586)
11-08 13:19:34.034: E/AndroidRuntime(20600):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-08 13:19:34.034: E/AndroidRuntime(20600):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
```

Please help,  as i have googled so many questions regarding this and couldn't seem to find a solution.
Thank you!

**EDIT**

Ihave corrected the error by myWebView and changed back to webview,  Thus resulting into a new error.  Please see updated question

**EDIT2**

```
@Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            progress = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            progress.setMessage("Please wait...");
            progress.setIndeterminate(false);
            progress.setCancelable(false);
            progress.show();
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;                
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, final String url) {
            progress.dismiss();
        }
    });
```

But this still seem to crash with same errors

Comment: you have not initialized your progress dialog...try to initialize it and run

Comment: How would i go about initializing it?

Comment: progress= ProgressDialog.show(this, "Title","Message", true);  before trying to show progres

Comment: Oh okay, have tried that now but then this happens `The method show(Context, CharSequence, CharSequence, boolean) in the type ProgressDialog is not applicable for the arguments (new WebViewClient(){}, String, String, boolean)`

Comment: Still facing issue or resolved?

Comment: Only got to test today, but yes all is working now thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not initialize your progress dialog,

```
progress= ProgressDialog.show(this, "Title","Message", true);
```

or,

```
        progress= new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        progress.setMessage("Please wait...");
        progress.setIndeterminate(false);
        progress.setCancelable(false);
        progress.show();
```

and you can call progress.dismiss() to hide the dialog

**EDIT**

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_maps, container, false);
WebView webview = (WebView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.webView2);
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(false);
webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index1.html");
progress= new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
  @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

        progress.setMessage("Please wait...");
        progress.setIndeterminate(false);
        progress.setCancelable(false);
        progress.show();
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;                
    }
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, final String url) {
        progress.dismiss();
    }
});

return rootView;
}
```

Comment: it is still giving me an error at onPageFinished (Null Pointer exception)  So i am thinking there is a issue at `@Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, final String url) {
            progress.dismiss();`

Comment: put  progress= new ProgressDialog(getActivity()); before webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){ this line and try again

Comment: you are initializing the progress inside the shouldOverrideUrlLoading method and it is not visible in onPageFinished.So try to initialize it outer of setWebViewClient method

Comment: This seems to work, but now last problem is the dialog disapears 2 seconds before the image is displayed?  Is there away of telling it to display longer until the image has loaded or put a time limit on it?

Comment: Use my solution, this will be better for you... with Progress display.

Answer (score 1):

I have used in my `WebView` that may helpful to you:

set `WebChromeClient` in `onCreate()` like

**`webView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient());`**

```
class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {

    ProgressDialog pDialog;

    public MyWebChromeClient() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(YourActivity.this); //Use getActivity(); for Fragment
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.setProgress(0);
        pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);

    }

    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) 
    {
        if(progress < 100 && !pDialog.isShowing()){
            pDialog.show();
        }
        pDialog.setProgress(progress);
        if(progress == 100) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

u can do something like this when ur loading resources

public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

```
    public void onLoadResource (WebView view, String url) {
        if (progressDialog == null) {
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Loading... ");
            progressDialog.show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: and how would you dismiss this progress dialog...?

Comment: than you have to implement didloadrequest or didfailed because either way you want stop your progress

Answer (score 0):

I made something similar to show a message when the page starts to loading and close it when it ends:

```
package com.veemesoft.radiostream.radiostream;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView webView;
    ImageButton goBack;
    TextView webViewTitle;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_view);
        webViewTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.web_view_title);
        String webViewTitleString = this.getIntent().getStringExtra("web_view_title");
        webViewTitle.setText(webViewTitleString);
        goBack = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.go_back);

        goBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                goToMainActivity();
            }
        });

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(false);
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                progressDialog.setMessage("Espere unos segundos...");
                progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
                progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
                progressDialog.show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, final String url) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        String url = this.getIntent().getStringExtra("url");
        webView.loadUrl(url);
    }

    private void goToMainActivity(){
        finish();
    }
}
```