# How to add spinning circle while loading a website in webview?

Tags: android, geometry

Is there a possibility, to add a circle that spins while it is loading a website in a webviewer? I haven't used such circle spinners before.

Thank you

Comment: Load your webview inside of an AsyncTask. That should give you enough handlers in preExecute() and onPostExecute()

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26988949/how-to-show-the-progress-bar-till-the-webview-content-is-appears-in-android

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/loadingPanel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:indeterminate="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

After finishing the layout, call this

```
findViewById(R.id.loadingPanel).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: And where I need to put the code in the Java Class?

Answer (score 0):

put progressbar in ur xml at desire position..

```
 <ProgressBar
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp" />

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/web_data"
    android:background="@color/transparent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Now handle it in ur Activity like this.

```
 private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        progress.setProgress(100);

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        setProgress(0);

    }
}
```

And set it to ur webview

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
```

Comment: It always crashes my app.